# How to Invoke Neo Smart Contract with some Neo tokens transferring to the smart contract?

Tags: blockchain, smartcontracts

I am creating an ICO and want to test it on a private network.
The `neo-gui` allows to invoke smart contract but does not send Neo asset token along with the invocation.
The Neon wallet provides to participate in ICO but it does not work on a private network setup using Docker.

Any workaround to call ICO smart contract's `mintToken` along with some Neo token transferred?

Comment: Can anyone add tags for neo, neo-gui, neon-wallet? It requires 1500 reputation.

Answer (score 0):

You could use [neo-python](https://github.com/CityOfZion/neo-python) to interact with your private net (I assume you already have this set up. If not, use for example [Effect.AI's NEO dev toolkit](https://github.com/effectai/neo-dev-toolkit)).

You can use the option `--privnet [host]` when starting neo-python to connect to your privnet